# implementing memcached: native django's modules or on (front server, reverse proxy) nginx

Tags: django, nginx, memcached

I have a setup like, `nginx` in the front for serving `static files` and `reverse proxying` to `apache` for `django` via `mod_wsgi` and I want to implement memcached in my setup. I don't have a huge traffic that my server will not handle today but it will get larger soon, it's best to be ready before.

I see two options for me: The first one is using django's native memcached module which handles many things automatically (afaik, confirm on comments pls), such as when a database entry is updated, it removes the related key, and maybe user authenticated pages (confirm please).

The other one is implementing memcached on nginx. The responsible structure for caching should be the front server seems more semantic to me; I am not quite sure of that but it is like division of responsibility. However, if I choose this was, I have to write more code for releasing cache keys on updates and user auth's. This will take some time of course, but I am in no rush.

The first one is the easy way, second one is harder but seems more logical. What would be the best option in terms of manageability and response times and the work required to implement? Would it worth it?

Also, there is only one site I am hosting that would require caching right now, but it will be more sites in the future and they *may not* be based on python. You might want to consider this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be an advantage to going the nginx route... but I'm not seeing it.

The advantages to using Django's module:

1. You can set data to cache, such as expensive queries and API call results, rather than be locked into caching the whole view.
2. It's easy, and then you can get back to making your application cool.